# Eclipse RCP trim status bar composite margins too big to display text

Tags: java, layout, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing a plug-in for a Eclipse RCP application. In this plug-in I want to set a text message and an icon in the trim status bar.

Considering my circumstances, I think I can scrap the following approaches:

- The **ActionBarAdvisor** approach seems to require the main application to set the status bar content. This is not suitable as the plug-in should be able to be independent to the application and vice versa.
- The **StatusLineContributionItem** seems to be bound to a certain view. In my case, the content has to be set globally for the whole application regardless of the currently selected view.

This leaves us to the [Contributing to the Status Bar/Trim in Eclipse RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810510/contributing-to-the-status-bar-trim-in-eclipse-rcp) approach. I've set up a small sample implementation following this approach:

The plugin.xml implementation:

```
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.status">
     <toolbar
           id="mypackage.toolbarContribution">
        <control
              class="mypackage.StatusBarContribution">
        </control>
     </toolbar>
  </menuContribution>
```

And the class implementation:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.menus.WorkbenchWindowControlContribution;

public class StatusBarContribution extends WorkbenchWindowControlContribution {

  protected Composite composite = null;

  @Override
  protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
    FillLayout layout = new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    layout.marginWidth = 0;        

    composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.BORDER);
    composite.setLayout(layout);  

    Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.NONE);
    text.setText("foo");

    return composite;
  }  
}
```

But this only gives me a small slice of text in the status bar:

[image]

I purposely set

```
composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NO_TRIM  | SWT.BORDER);
```

to be able to see the layout margins:

As you can see, the created composite height is way to low to display the text correctly: [image: status bar's composite borders]

So, am I missing here something - e.g. using another margin property or SWT bit style?

Comment: You could try using GridLayout rather than FillLayour. Use GridData with a width and height hint on the Text.

Comment: Hi Greg, I tried the following without any success after changing the layout to GridLayout:

`GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, false, true);
gridData.heightHint = text.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y;
text.setLayoutData(gridData);`

Comment: @Niklas did you have any success with this problem? I have just upgraded my RCP app from Kepler to 2020-03 and now have the same problem as you have described.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a dummy command contribution in addition to the control, layout works.