# Contributing to the Status Bar/Trim in Eclipse RCP 3.x Text Editor

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Following the question ([Contributing to the Status Bar/Trim in Eclipse RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810510/contributing-to-the-status-bar-trim-in-eclipse-rcp)) I want to contribute to the status bar of my  RCP (3.x) text editor.

In the `org.eclipse.ui.menuContributions` extensions, I have to use `toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.status` as the locationURI. So I can can contribute commands/custom controls to the status bar.

Since my app is a text editor, I want to use the same controls (Labels) that the Eclipse IDE uses for Insert/OverWrite and line caret information (line and column position).

Which are the classes required to show such information?

[image]

Comment: If your editor is based on `AbstractTextEditor` (or one of its subclasses) most of this should be automatic. You can also call `AbstractTextEditor.updateStatusField`

Comment: @greg-449, The editor extends ```org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor```, so is based on ```AbstractTextEditor```, but I dont know how to connect it with the status bar that I have declared in ```ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor``` setting up the ```IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer``` (```configurer.setShowStatusLine(true)```)

Comment: Well TextEditor should find the standard status line automatically. The editor action contributor class (`BasicTextEditorActionContributor` for example) defines status fields in the status area. `ITextEditorActionConstants.STATUS_xxx` defines ids for the standard status area)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found. After @greg-449 commnet I realized that I have not included the contribution class (`BasicTextEditorActionContributor`) into the extension point.

This is the final extension to the editor plugin:

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            class="yourEditorClass"
            contributorClass="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BasicTextEditorActionContributor"
            default="false"
            icon="icons/editorIcon.png"
            id="youreditorId"
            name="your editor name">
      </editor>    
</extension>
```